# Arduino - SevSeg Shift Library issues

Tags: arduino

The project I am trying to create is a voltage breaker circuit; it essentially measures the voltage of a circuit by using a sensor and if it is over the user-selected amount using a potentiometer, via a relay it will cut the power to rest of a circuit: all powered and processed by an Arduino.

I have got the circuit working with an LCD however it is a bit clunky and unnecessary to have an lcd for representing the two digits so I looked for an alternative.

The aim is to replace it with a four digit eight segment display combined with a shift register(I have ran out of GPIO pins on the Arduino Nano)however I can't seem to do it.

Here is the code:

```
#include <SevSegShift.h>

const int SHIFT_PIN_DS  = 8; /* Data input PIN */
const int SHIFT_PIN_STCP = 7; /* Shift Register Storage PIN */
const int SHIFT_PIN_SHCP = 6; /* Shift Register Shift PIN */

//Instantiate a seven segment controller object (with Shift Register functionality)
SevSegShift sevsegshift(
                  SHIFT_PIN_DS, 
                  SHIFT_PIN_SHCP, 
                  SHIFT_PIN_STCP, 
                  1, /* number of shift registers there is only 1 Shiftregister 
                        used for all Segments (digits are on Controller)
                        default value = 2 (see SevSegShift example)
                        */
                  true /* Digits are connected to Arduino directly 
                          default value = false (see SevSegShift example)
                        */
                );

void setup() {
  byte numDigits = 4;
  byte digitPins[] = {5, 4, 3, 2}; // These are the PINS of the ** Arduino **
  byte segmentPins[] = {0, 2, 4, 6, 7, 1, 3, 5}; // these are the PINs of the ** Shift register **
  bool resistorsOnSegments = false; // 'false' means resistors are on digit pins
  byte hardwareConfig = COMMON_CATHODE; // See README.md for options
  bool updateWithDelays = false; // Default 'false' is Recommended
  bool leadingZeros = false; // Use 'true' if you'd like to keep the leading zeros
  bool disableDecPoint = false; // Use 'true' if your decimal point doesn't exist or isn't connected. Then, you only need to specify 7 segmentPins[]

  SevSeg.begin(hardwareConfig, numDigits, digitPins, segmentPins, resistorsOnSegments, updateWithDelays, leadingZeros, disableDecPoint);
  
}
```

The error I keep getting is:

**exit status 1
expected unqualified-id before '.' token**

And the line highlighted is:

**SevSeg.begin(hardwareConfig, numDigits, digitPins, segmentPins, resistorsOnSegments, updateWithDelays, leadingZeros, disableDecPoint);**

Does anyone know what this might mean?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason that this is, is because you have typed the variable incorrectly, rather than
`SevSeg` (the name of the class from the library), you need to type `sevsegshift`, the name of the instance of the class you created.

```
#include <SevSegShift.h>

const int SHIFT_PIN_DS  = 8; /* Data input PIN */
const int SHIFT_PIN_STCP = 7; /* Shift Register Storage PIN */
const int SHIFT_PIN_SHCP = 6; /* Shift Register Shift PIN */

//Instantiate a seven segment controller object (with Shift Register functionality)
SevSegShift sevsegshift(
                  SHIFT_PIN_DS, 
                  SHIFT_PIN_SHCP, 
                  SHIFT_PIN_STCP, 
                  1, /* number of shift registers there is only 1 Shiftregister 
                        used for all Segments (digits are on Controller)
                        default value = 2 (see SevSegShift example)
                        */
                  true /* Digits are connected to Arduino directly 
                          default value = false (see SevSegShift example)
                        */
                );

void setup() {
  byte numDigits = 4;
  byte digitPins[] = {5, 4, 3, 2}; // These are the PINS of the ** Arduino **
  byte segmentPins[] = {0, 2, 4, 6, 7, 1, 3, 5}; // these are the PINs of the ** Shift register **
  bool resistorsOnSegments = false; // 'false' means resistors are on digit pins
  byte hardwareConfig = COMMON_CATHODE; // See README.md for options
  bool updateWithDelays = false; // Default 'false' is Recommended
  bool leadingZeros = false; // Use 'true' if you'd like to keep the leading zeros
  bool disableDecPoint = false; // Use 'true' if your decimal point doesn't exist or isn't connected. Then, you only need to specify 7 segmentPins[]

  sevsegshift.begin(hardwareConfig, numDigits, digitPins, segmentPins, resistorsOnSegments, updateWithDelays, leadingZeros, disableDecPoint);
  
}
```

Hope this answered your question!